# bitwise logical operators in java

Tags: java, reverse, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to get a reverse of a but somethings goes wrong.

```
String binary[]={
        "0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101",
        "0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1100",
        "1101","1110","1111"
    };
    int a=3;
    int b=6;
    int c=a|b;
    int d=a&b;
    int e=a^b;
    int f=(~a &b) | (a&~b);
    int g= ~a & 0x0f;

    System.out.println(" a="+binary[a]);
    System.out.println(" b="+binary[b]);
    System.out.println(" a|b="+binary[c]);
    System.out.println(" a&b="+binary[d]);
    System.out.println(" a^b="+binary[e]);
    System.out.println(" ~a&b|a&~b="+binary[f]);
    System.out.println(" ~a="+binary[g]);**
```

otput is:

```
 a=0011
 b=0110
 a|b=0111
 a&b=0010
 a^b=0101
 ~a&b|a&~b=0101
 ~a=1101
```

The last one is wrong.a's reverse must be 1100.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The proper value for 11 (`1011`) is missing.

Comment: I realised it.Thanks for help RealSkeptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You binary strings aren't correct, the bit shifts are, this is the correct array of binary strings:

```
String binary[]={
            "0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101",
            "0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011",
            "1100","1101","1110", "1111"
    };
```

And with your code this is the output:

```
a=0011
b=0110
a|b=0111
a&b=0010
a^b=0101
~a&b|a&~b=0101
~a=1100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String binary[]={
    "0000","0001","0010","0011",
    "0100","0101","0110","0111",
    "1000","1001","1010","1011",
    "1100","1101","1110","1111"
};
```

Elementary: You missed one binary value. ORdering in a more obvious pattern helps.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for finding the quote.